# How to redirect mobile users from a desktop homepage to a mobile version

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mobile, responsive, elementor

Website is built with Elementor Pro and EasyWP.
Website uses outdated plugin to redirect mobile users.
Website will not be rebuilt with responsive design.

How do I implement a script to replace this outdated plugin?

Thus far, I've tried several other plugins with varying success. Generally, they function correctly when accessing the website with a Pixel 2XL (released 2017, 2880x1440 screen resolution), however do not work with newer phones (even with smaller screen resolutions).

This leads me to believe these plugins trigger redirects based on outdated browser types rather than screen resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet in your desktop version. This will put the custom code in the footer of your theme and all mobile users will be redirected to the mobile version of your site. Just put this in functions.php of your theme to make it work

```php
function custom_footer_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
      var loc = window.location;
      if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
        loc.pathname.indexOf('/mobile-') === -1) {
           loc.href = loc.origin + '/mobile-' + loc.pathname.substr(1, loc.pathname.length);
      }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_footer_script' );
```

Comment: In this case, the website does not have a subdomain for the mobile version. Rather, it simply uses duplicate pages with altered URLs. 
desktop homepage: "https://example.com"
mobile homepage: "https://example.com/mobile-home"
How to avoid redirect loop with the provided script? Is there an if statement that can be added? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that info. Please check the improved code. So this will now run only on mobile devices when a desktop page is open (url does not start with "/mobile-"). If both conditiions are satisfied, you'll get redirected to the same page with "/mobile-" prefix

Comment: I made a couple small adjustments:
i) revised "mobile-" on line 6 to "mobile" ii) revised my mobile homepage from "example.com/mobile-home" to "example.com/mobile" (because my desktop homepage is "example.com" rather than "example.com/home". Thought I'd share in case someone else is looking for the same solution. It works perfectly now, thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Glad it worked well, you're welcome!